# JavaScript REGEX replacement with the content inside from an external text file

Tags: javascript, html, regex

Here is my code in which the below comment pattern will replaced with new content. And it's working fine.

Inside HTML:

```
<div id="content">
    <!-- ### START CONTENT ### -->
    <p>Some text.</p>
    <!-- ### END CONTENT ### -->
</div>
```

Javascript Code:

```
var str = document.getElementById("content").innerHTML; 
    var txt = str.replace(/<!-- ### START CONTENT ### -->([\s\S]*?)<!-- ### END CONTENT ### -->/g, '<div id="example">Some replaced example stuff !!</div>');
    document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = txt;
```

But, my question is.. I want to replace a large block of html code instead of `<div id="example">Some replaced example stuff !!</div>`.

So, for this..  i plan to save the large block of html code inside a text file and the text file will be called and the content inside the file will be displayed when the pattern matches.

Is it possible to replace the content from an external text file ?

Note: The text file will be placed in the root directory itself..

Jsfiddle Link: http://jsfiddle.net/Lipak/2efm1o4c/9/

Large block of html code link: http://jsfiddle.net/Lipak/zn8fj5q3/

Comment: Of course. Just AJAX it in.

Comment: Could you please explain it. Thanks :)

Comment: Why don't you generate HTML via JavaScript instead of treating it like a string?

Comment: Could you please explain how to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

I'd take a different approach, which doesn't require HTML comments nor regexp replaces. Put the name of the text file to replace the contents with as a data attribute on the element:

```
<div id="content" data-replace-file="foo.html">
```

Find all the related elements and do the replace:

```
// Find all the elements to be replaced.
var replace = document.querySelectorAll('[data-replace-file]');

// Loop across elements, replacing each one.
for (var i=0; i<replace.length; i++) {
  var elt = replace[i];
  var file = elt.dataset.replaceFile;
  $(elt).load(file);
}
```

If you insist on your plan to use the HTML comments, then

```
var elt = document.getElementById("content");
var str = elt.innerHTML;
var regexp = /(<!-- ### START CONTENT ### -->)([\s\S]*?)(<!-- ### END CONTENT ### -->)/;

if (regexp.test(str)) {
  $.get("blah.html", function(data) {
    elt.innerHTML = str.replace(regexp, "$1" + data + "$3");      
  });
}
```

Here is an entire HTML file which works fine in my environment:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>

<div id="content">
    <!-- ### START CONTENT ### -->replace me<!-- ### END CONTENT ### -->
</div>

<button onclick="go()">Go</button>

<script>
  function go() {
    var elt = document.getElementById("content");
    var str = elt.innerHTML;
    var regexp = /(<!-- ### START CONTENT ### -->)([\s\S]*?)(<!-- ### END CONTENT ### -->)/;

    if (regexp.test(str)) {
      $.get("blah.html", function(data) {
        elt.innerHTML = str.replace(regexp, "$1" + data + "$3");
      });
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply ! But, what i actually want is that.. first of all, when it will match the above comment pattern (START and END).. then the content inside the text file should replace inside "content" ID. Or else if you have any other idea to replace large block of code using the above javascript code.. please tell me. Thanks.. :)

Comment: Yes, I know that's what you actually want. You described it in your question. What I am saying is, that is not a very good way to do it. Perhaps it would help if you explained your actual problem, instead of the way that you have decided to try to solve it. There are many client/server architectures, involving various ways to update content based on ajax calls, but this is not one of the best ones. You also need to specify what your target environments are. Depending on that, there may be much better, more modern solutions such as HTML imports or web components. Anyway, see updated answer.

Comment: Thank ! :) Actually i'm building a simple html code conversion web app (Totally find and replace comment pattern situation like above).. where user input the html template code in a textbox.. and when user click a button.. the output will be converted code. That's it. I'm new to web programming.. Don't know this is good way to do. Could you please guide me ?

Comment: In your particular case an iframe does not sound like a bad solution.

Comment: The above code by you isn't working. In console error is: "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined" . Any solution ?

Comment: Now no console error. In console it's showing "XHR finished loading: GET "http://localhost/test.html"." But the content is not showing in output from this external html file.

Comment: Try debugging. Place a breakpoint at the `if (regexp...)` line and examine its value, tracing through to see if the `if` branch is taken. Stop at the `elt.innerHTML =` line. Examine the value of the `data` variable. Examine `elt.innerHTML`, before and after being replaced.

Comment: "$1" + data + "$3" :- What does it mean ?

Comment: hey !! "innerHTML" showing "undefined" .. what is the issue ?

Comment: Regarding the meaning of `"$1" + data + "$3"`, please consult the documentation for `String#replace`.

Comment: Which `innerHMTL` is undefined, where?

Comment: elt.innherHTML = str.replace(regexp, "$1" + data + "$3");  In this line "innerHTML" is undefined.

Comment: I'll let you debug that yourself. Hint: `innherHTML` might be a typo.

Comment: Huh !!! First time i'm debugging .. it's tough enough :P .. It seems everything is fine.. i think finally it should return something. Right ?

Comment: Could please fix this. I'm unable to fix this.

Comment: I have tested this and it works fine. So the problem must lie elsewhere. Perhaps `blah.html` cannot be found on your server. What does the network tab show?

Comment: There is no error in console. I'm using with localhost and all files (index.html , test.html) are in same "www" folder. What is the problem here ? :(

Comment: I was not talking about the console per se, but rather the network tab, where you can see the request for `blah.html` (or `test.html`--which is it?), and whether or not it succeeded. Please post your HTML in its entirety.

Comment: No success !! i don't know whats wrong here.. :( In network tab.. it's showing test.html..

Comment: Even test.html file loading successfully.. i think there is regex problem..it's not able to match and replace the code.